# python pandas ipython matplotlib financial timeserie

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython

I have a dataframe such as follow

```
                       open     high      low    close  volume
timestamp                                                      
2000-02-01 00:30:00  1401.00  1401.50  1400.50  1401.25       8
2000-02-01 01:00:00  1401.50  1401.50  1400.25  1400.25      10
2000-02-01 01:30:00  1400.25  1401.00  1399.50  1400.75      18
2000-02-01 02:00:00  1400.50  1401.00  1399.75  1400.00      15
2000-02-01 02:30:00  1399.75  1399.75  1399.25  1399.25       6
2000-02-01 03:00:00  1400.00  1400.00  1399.50  1399.50       6
2000-02-01 03:30:00  1399.25  1399.25  1398.25  1398.25      10
2000-02-01 04:00:00  1398.50  1399.00  1398.25  1398.75       7
2000-02-01 04:30:00  1399.00  1400.25  1399.00  1400.00      13
2000-02-01 05:00:00  1399.75  1400.50  1399.25  1400.25      26
2000-02-01 05:30:00  1400.00  1400.75  1399.50  1400.50      24
2000-02-01 06:00:00  1400.00  1400.00  1399.00  1399.25      23
2000-02-01 06:30:00  1399.50  1404.00  1399.50  1403.50      96
2000-02-01 07:00:00  1403.50  1405.00  1402.50  1402.50     108
2000-02-01 07:30:00  1402.50  1404.50  1400.50  1401.00     162
2000-02-01 08:00:00  1400.75  1402.50  1399.50  1401.25     166
2000-02-01 08:30:00  1401.25  1403.75  1397.25  1398.25    2009
2000-02-01 09:00:00  1398.50  1403.75  1391.25  1395.50    2497
2000-02-01 09:30:00  1395.50  1404.25  1394.75  1400.75    2071
2000-02-01 10:00:00  1400.75  1404.50  1399.75  1403.00    1528
2000-02-01 10:30:00  1403.00  1405.25  1399.25  1399.50    1253
2000-02-01 11:00:00  1399.25  1407.75  1398.25  1407.25    1226
2000-02-01 11:30:00  1407.00  1409.00  1406.00  1408.75    1079
2000-02-01 12:00:00  1408.75  1411.50  1408.00  1409.50    1091
2000-02-01 12:30:00  1409.75  1410.00  1405.00  1406.25    1129
2000-02-01 13:00:00  1406.25  1412.50  1405.50  1409.50    1361
```

I want to print it in a ipython notebook with the function matplotlib.finance.

I have tried the following

```
import matplotlib.finance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax, data)
```

where data is my dataframe. This is the example given in the book python for finance, however in that case the data is retrieved directly form the yahoo website. I havent found a way to repurpose that example - i'm quite new to python and i really don't know what to start trying. All help is appreciated. Thx!

Comment: what specifically is the problem?

Comment: I would just need a simple example of syntax that works to have a pandas dataframe thats already formatted as ohlc to plot as a candlestick chart... i m quite lost and i can tell its gonna take hours (if not days considering that i only have few hours to do that outside of my regular job) to figure out by browsing the web, so if someone has already that piece of knowledge to share that would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.finance` already has a yahoo reader that will bring back the data in the appropriate format:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc, candlestick_ohlc

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc('GOOG', (2016, 11, 1), (2016, 11, 30))
candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.5)
plt.show()
```

You will need to actually update the axes to present label with dates.

Converting from a `pandas` dataframe. The only difference between your `dataframe` and the default one from `pandas.datareader` is the label of your index (`timestamp` vs `Date`) so just rename in the example below. You will need `reset_index` and reorder (`reindex`) your columns into OCHL format:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

data = web.get_data_yahoo('AMZN', '11/1/2016', '12/1/2016')
quotes = data.reset_index().reindex_axis(['Date','Open','Close','High','Low'], axis=1)
quotes['Date'] = quotes['Date'].astype(int)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes.values, width=0.5)
plt.show()
```

But need to fix the x-axis.

Comment: Yes I know about that example.
I dont want to retrieve data from yahoo - I want to plot a pandas dataframe such as the one i show above (which i have saved as a .h5 for completeness of description) , and i dont know how to repurpose that snippet that you are providing for my specific case.